# How can I save the ID in React by name

Tags: reactjs

I'm still quite new to React and currently have a problem. I created a form consisting of input fields and select menus. In the case of the input fields, the data is also easily transmitted to the database and entered in the columns. With the select menus, I get the data from the database and only display the names. Based on the name, the value should then be entered in the linked table.
Based on the name, the value should then be entered in the linked table. But he does not pass on the value. What can I do?
Here is the code for the form:

```
export default class DatensatzHinzufuegenForm extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onChangeKKS = this.onChangeKKS.bind(this);
        this.onChangeKurztext = this.onChangeKurztext.bind(this);
        this.onChangeKraftwerk = this.onChangeKraftwerk.bind(this);
        this.onChangeSoftware = this.onChangeSoftware.bind(this);
        this.onChangeModell = this.onChangeModell.bind(this);
        this.onChangeBackup= this.onChangeBackup.bind(this);
        this.onChangeIBS = this.onChangeIBS.bind(this);
        this.onChangeBackuptest= this.onChangeBackuptest.bind(this);
        this.onChangePatch = this.onChangePatch.bind(this);
        this.onChangeCheckliste= this.onChangeCheckliste.bind(this);
        this.saveKomponente = this.saveKomponente.bind(this);
        this.newKomponente = this.newKomponente.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            aktuellesIT_Element: {
                it_element_id: null,
                kw_id: null,
                kks: "",
                kurztext:"",
                systemeinheit_id: null,
                system_id: null,
                status_usb_id: null,
                virenschutz_hersteller_id: null,
                status_rj45_id: null,
                betriebssystem_id: null,
                status_firewall_id: null,
                status_virenschutz_id: null,
                systemhersteller_id: null,
                modell: "",
                office_id: null,
                sonstige_sw:"",
                firmwareversion:"",
                backup: "",
                backup_test: "",
                ibs_datum: "",
                checkliste: "",

                submitted: false
            },
        };
    }

    onChangeKKS(e) {
        this.setState({
            kks: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeKurztext(e) {
        this.setState({
            kurztext: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeModell(e) {
        this.setState({
            modell: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeKraftwerk(e) {
        this.setState({
            kw_id: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangePatch(e) {
        this.setState({
            firmware: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeCheckliste(e) {
        this.setState({
            checkliste: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeBackup(e) {
        this.setState({
            backup: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeBackuptest(e) {
        this.setState({
            backup_test: e.target.value
        });
    }
    onChangeIBS(e) {
        this.setState({
            ibs_datum: e.target.value
        });
    }

    onChangeSoftware(e) {
        this.setState({
            sonstige_sw: e.target.value
        });
    }

    saveKomponente() {
        var data = {
            kw_id: this.state.kw_id,
            kks: this.state.kks,
            kurztext:this.state.kurztext,
            systemeinheit_id: this.state.systemeinheit_id,
            system_id: this.state.system_id,
            status_usb_id: this.state.status_usb_id,
            virenschutz_hersteller_id: this.state.virenschutz_hersteller_id,
            status_rj45_id: this.state.status_rj45_id,
            betriebssystem_id: this.state.betriebssystem_id,
            status_firewall_id: this.state.status_firewall_id,
            status_virenschutz_id: this.state.status_virenschutz_id,
            systemhersteller_id: this.state.systemhersteller_id,
            modell: this.state.modell,
            office_id: this.state.office_id,
            sonstige_sw:this.state.sonstige_sw,
            firmwareversion:this.state.firmwareversion,
            backup: this.state.backup,
            backup_test: this.state.backup_test,
            ibs_datum: this.state.ibs_datum,
            checkliste: this.state.checkliste,
        };

        KomponentDataService.create(data)
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    it_element_id: response.data.it_element_id,
                    kw_id: response.data.kw_id,
                    kks: response.data.kks,
                    kurztext:response.data.kurztext,
                    systemeinheit_id: response.data.systemeinheit_id,
                    system_id: response.data.system_id,
                    status_usb_id: response.data.status_usb_id,
                    virenschutz_hersteller_id: response.data.virenschutz_hersteller_id,
                    status_rj45_id: response.data.status_rj45_id,
                    betriebssystem_id: response.data.betriebssystem_id,
                    status_firewall_id: response.data.status_firewall_id,
                    status_virenschutz_id: response.data.status_virenschutz_id,
                    systemhersteller_id: response.data.systemhersteller_id,
                    modell: response.data.modell,
                    office_id: response.data.office_id,
                    sonstige_sw:response.data.sonstige_sw,
                    firmwareversion:response.data.firmwareversion,
                    backup: response.data.backup,
                    backup_test: response.data.backup_test,
                    ibs_datum: response.data.ibs_datum,
                    checkliste: response.data.checkliste,

                    submitted: true
                });
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
            });
    }

    newKomponente() {
        this.setState({
            it_element_id: null,
            kw_id: null,
            kks: "",
            kurztext:"",
            systemeinheit_id: null,
            system_id: null,
            status_usb_id: null,
            virenschutz_hersteller_id: null,
            status_rj45_id: null,
            betriebssystem_id: null,
            status_firewall_id: null,
            status_virenschutz_id: null,
            systemhersteller_id: null,
            modell: "",
            office_id: null,
            sonstige_sw:"",
            firmwareversion:"",
            backup: "",
            backup_test: "",
            ibs_datum: "",
            checkliste: "",

            submitted: false
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="submit-form">
                {this.state.submitted ? (
                    <div>
                        <h4>Erfolgreich {this.state.kks} hinzugefügt!</h4>
                        <button onClick={this.newKomponente}>
                            Hinzufügen
                        </button>
                        <Button>
                            <Link
                                to={"/komponentenuebersicht"}>
                                Abbruch
                            </Link>
                        </Button>{' '}
                    </div>
                ) : (
                    <div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="kks">KKS: </label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                id="kks"
                                required
                                value={this.state.kks}
                                onChange={this.onChangeKKS}
                                name="kks"
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="kw_id">Standort: </label><br/>
                            <Kraftwerk
                                id="kw_id"
                                required
                                value={this.state.kw_id}
                                onChange={this.onChangeKraftwerk}
                                name="kw_id"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="kurztext">Kurztext: </label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                id="kurztext"
                                required
                                value={this.state.kurztext}
                                onChange={this.onChangeKurztext}
                                name="kurztext"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="systemeinheit_id">Systemeinheit: </label><br/>
                            <Systemeinheit/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="system_id">System: </label><br/>
                            <System/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="betriebssystem_id">Betriebssystem: </label><br/>
                            <Betriebssystem/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="systemhersteller_id">Systemhersteller: </label><br/>
                            <Systemhersteller/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="virenschutz_hersteller_id">Virenschutzhersteller: </label><br/>
                            <Virenschutzhersteller/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="modell">Modell: </label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                id="modell"
                                required
                                value={this.state.modell}
                                onChange={this.onChangeModell}
                                name="modell"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="firmware">Patchzustand: </label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                id="firmware"
                                required
                                value={this.state.firmware}
                                onChange={this.onChangePatch}
                                name="firmware"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="backup">Backup: </label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                id="backup"
                                required
                                value={this.state.backup}
                                onChange={this.onChangeBackup}
                                name="backup"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="backup_test">Backuptest: </label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                id="backup_test"
                                required
                                value={this.state.backup_test}
                                onChange={this.onChangeBackuptest}
                                name="backup_test"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="ibs_datum">Inbetriebsetzungsjahr: </label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                id="ibs_datum"
                                required
                                value={this.state.ibs_datum}
                                onChange={this.onChangeIBS}
                                name="ibs_datum"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="status_usb_id">USB-Status: </label><br/>
                            <USB/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="status_firewall_id">Firewallstautus: </label><br/>
                            <Firewall/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="status_rj45_id">RJ45-Status: </label><br/>
                            <RJ45/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="status_virenschutz_id">Virenschutzstatus: </label><br/>
                            <Virenschutz/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="office_id">Office: </label><br/>
                            <Office/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="sonstige_sw">Sonstige Software: </label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                id="sonstige_sw"
                                required
                                value={this.state.sonstige_sw}
                                onChange={this.onChangeSoftware}
                                name="sonstige_sw"
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="checkliste">Checkliste: </label>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control"
                                id="checkliste"
                                required
                                value={this.state.checkliste}
                                onChange={this.onChangeCheckliste}
                                name="checkliste"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <button onClick={this.saveKomponente} className="btn btn-success">
                            Speichern
                        </button>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The code for one select menu:

```
import React from "react";
import { Container} from "react-bootstrap";
import KraftwerkDataService from "../../services/kraftwerk.service";

export const KraftwerkSpin = (props) => (
    <div className="form-group">
        <strong>{props.kraftwerk_name}</strong>
        <select
            className="form-control"
            onChange={props.kraftwerk_name}
        >
            <option defaultValue>Standort{props.kraftwerk_name}</option>
            {props.options.map((item, index) => (
                <option key={index} value={item.kw_id}>
                    {item.kraftwerk_name} - {item.kw_id}
                </option>
            ))}
        </select>
    </div>
)

export default class Kraftwerk extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.retrieveKraftwerk = this.retrieveKraftwerk.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            kraftwerk: [],
            value: '',
        }
    }

    retrieveKraftwerk() {
        KraftwerkDataService.getAll()
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    kraftwerk: response.data
                });
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.retrieveKraftwerk();
    }
    onChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ value: event.target.value })
    }

    changeValue(kw_id) {
        this.setState({dropDownValue: kw_id})
    }

    render() {

        return(
            <Container>
                <KraftwerkSpin
                    name={this.state.kraftwerk_name}
                    options={this.state.kraftwerk}
                    onChange={this.changeValue}
                />
            </Container>
        )
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.
I have already tried to assign the value as with the input field, but without success